# Django 2.0 syndication feed not working with Wordpress reader

Tags: python, django, rss, feed

I followed the following material to create a feed for my site -

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/syndication/

https://www.bedjango.com/blog/how-generate-feeds-using-django/

My code is as below

```
# feeds.py
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Article

class ArticleFeed(Feed):
  title = "Arushi Pant"
  link = "/"
  description = "Always eager to learn. Determined to make the best of 
                    the time I've got on Earth."

  def items(self):
      return Article.objects.filter(publishedDate__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-publishedDate')[:30]

  def item_title(self, item):
      return item.title

  def item_description(self, item):
      return item.shortDescription

  def item_link(self, item):
     return reverse('post_detail', args=[item.slug, item.pk])
```

The feed is online at http://arushipant.pratibimb.co/feed/

I also checked that it was valid here - https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi
And it says this is a valid RSS feed.

Now, I am trying to follow this blog from Wordpress Reader.

The blog gets followed, but there are no posts being shown as published.

Is there some other way I should be making feeds if I want others to follow my blog from Wordpress?

Edit - I am using Django 2.0.6, Python 3.5